# Error with FACEBOOK API GRAPH to check DEVICE LOGIN STATUS

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting base in official website https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices/

I have my code:

```
            do
            {                    

                UrlRequisicao = @"https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/device/login_status?";
                UrlRequisicao = UrlRequisicao + @"access_token=37382829968|3998b73ca7a3338d390356ee987";
                UrlRequisicao = UrlRequisicao + @"&code=92a2b2e351f2b0b3503b2de251132f47"; // Example only

                var req2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UrlRequisicao);
                req2.Method = "POST";
                req2.Accept = _mediaType;
                req2.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, _charSet);

                var response2 = (HttpWebResponse)req2.GetResponse();
                var bodyResposta2 = response2.GetResponseStream();
                using (var reader2 = new StreamReader(bodyResposta2))
                {
                    var jsonretorno = reader2.ReadToEnd();
                    JObject Feed = JObject.Parse(jsonretorno);
                    MessageBox.Show(jsonretorno);
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            }
            while (sonda);
```

But it is giving error in the second requisition in `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/device/login_status?`
The error is as follows:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Request Incorrect.

Comment: I think you need to send access token and code as actual POST parameters here, right now you just passed them along as query string parameters in the URL.

Comment: In step 1 I also use it as a URL. It worked normally, I even get the code.

Comment: Can you try the same request in Graph API Explorer, and see if it succeeds there?